# Change the message "Run \LaTeX{} again to produce the table" for exam class

Tags: exam

In exam class, we can produce the grading table, with the command `\gradetable`. For the first compilation, this command produces the message `Run \LaTeX{} again to produce the table`, and produces the gradetable in the second compilation. I want to personalize this message of first compilation to, for example, "The Grades' table will be produced in the second compilation". I find in the file `exam.cls` that the message is produced by the following macro:

```
\def\check@secondrun#1{%
  % The function \ii@gtable already made sure that this isn't the
  % first run of latex.  To do a table indexed by pages, though, we
  % have to also make sure it's not the second run of latex.
  % We get here from \find@prange; the argument is either ``v'' or
  % ``h''.
  % Check that there's enough info from the .aux file to do a page
  % indexed grade table.  If so, call \tbl@v@or@h{#1}:
  \@ifundefined{pointsonpage@\romannumeral
               \csname lastpage@withpoints\endcsname}%
    {\@ifundefined{bonuspointsonpage@\romannumeral
               \csname lastpage@withbonuspoints\endcsname}%
        {\ClassWarning{exam}{%
           You must run LaTeX again to produce the table.\MessageBreak}%
           \fbox{Run \LaTeX{} again to produce the table}%
        }%
        {\tbl@v@or@h{#1}%
        }%
    }%
    {\tbl@v@or@h{#1}%
    }%
}% check@secondrun
```

so how can I change the message inside it ?

**The macro I gave was wrong**

The macro which produces the message is the following one:

```
\def\ii@gtable#1[#2]{%
  % We get here from \i@gtable.
  % We make sure the user said \addpoints, and then make sure
  % that this isn't the first run of LaTeX (by checking that
  % \exam@numpoints is defined).  If both of those are OK,
  % we go to \find@p@or@q@range to see whether we're doing a table
  % indexed by questions or by pages.
  \if@addpoints
    \@ifundefined{exam@numpoints}%
      {\ClassWarning{exam}%
        {%
          You must run LaTeX again to produce the
            table.\MessageBreak
        }%
        \fbox{Run \LaTeX{} again to produce the table}%
      }%
      {\find@p@or@q@range{#1}{#2}}%
  \else
    \ClassError{exam}{%
      You must give the command \protect\addpoints\MessageBreak
      \space\space in order to create a grade table.\MessageBreak
      }{%
      If you don't give the command \protect\addpoints\MessageBreak
      \space\space then we're not keeping track of point values.
      \MessageBreak
      }%
  \fi
}% ii@gtable
```

I give an MWE of the solution, based on the answer given:

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\ii@gtable
  {Run \LaTeX{} again to produce the table}
  {The Grades' table will be produced in the second compilation}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\gradetable
\begin{questions}
\question A question
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

and it's compilation, where one can see the suitable message:

[image]

Comment: What about: `\fbox{Run \LaTeX{} again to produce the table}` to `\fbox{The Grades' table will be produced in the second compilation}`?

Comment: @koleygr This is possible, but you must put all the commands for producing table between `makeatletter` `makeatother`, and my question was: "what must change?". The solution given by @PhelypeOleinik, it's second part, is the good answer I think

Comment: I couldn't know if you would like to change the cls file or to add something in your preamble... A change in the cls file could work for you even if it is not usually advisable (due to difficulties in sharing). In this case your document would work anyway, but would produce other message in other pc (without changed the cls). I am not sure if this makes a big difference since seems to be something not really important in the document and not makes no change in the final pdf. If you are using it inside some program, the program could just compile by its own again with easy methods

Comment: Generally, my approach is to absolutely not change anything in the original files of packages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you are wrong. The message you see is produced by the `\ii@gtable` macro. To change the message you can redefine the `\ii@gtable` macro:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ii@gtable#1[#2]{%
  \if@addpoints
    \@ifundefined{exam@numpoints}%
      {\ClassWarning{exam}%
        {%
          You must run LaTeX again to produce the
            table.\MessageBreak
        }%
        \fbox{The Grades' table will be produced in the second compilation}%
      }%
      {\do@table{#1}{#2}}%
  \else
    \ClassError{exam}{%
      You must give the command \protect\addpoints\MessageBreak
      \space\space in order to create a grade table.\MessageBreak
      }{%
      If you don't give the command \protect\addpoints\MessageBreak
      \space\space then we're not keeping track of point values.
      \MessageBreak
      }%
  \fi
}% ii@gtable
\makeatother
```

or, to reduce code clutter, you can patch it:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\ii@gtable
  {Run \LaTeX{} again to produce the table}
  {The Grades' table will be produced in the second compilation}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Would you see my update please, where one can see that the macro is not useful

Comment: Actually, the macro *is* useful and did what we asked it to do. The problem was that the macro `\check@secondrun` is not the responsible for the message you see, the macro you were looking for is `\ii@gtable`. The approach to solve the problem, though, is the same. This kind of misunderstanding happens a lot when a question of this kind does not have a MWE for we to run tests, then every solution is just a guess. I changed my answer to do what you want.

Comment: Also, "updated" questions are very likely to be ignored since, theoretically, you could edit your question over and over asking for something different. To get better chances of an answer, post a new question instead ;)

Comment: I was wrong and I think that I will adapt-update my question to your answer. When I said that the macro is not useful, I meaned that it's not for my purpose With my excuses and my many thanks for your disponibility.

Comment: Would you see my updated question. With my excuses and my many thanks another time.

Comment: No problem :) But are you still having trouble?

Comment: The lesson is: must always produce a MWE !